# Insert instance of class into the vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have created a class `Location`, which is a parent class for classes `City` and `Village`. I have a `vector<Location>` and now I need to insert `City` or `Village` into this `vector`. I tried for example following:

```
    vector<Location> locations;
    locations.push_back(new City("New York", 9000, 1, 2));
```

or

```
    vector<Location> locations;
    Location* loc = new City("New York", 9000, 1, 2);
    locations.push_back(loc);
```

but nothing works. Can you give me an advice, please? I'm not a C++ programmer, I'm programming in Java normally, so please help me.

Comment: Use a container that stores pointers to store the instances (`std::vector<Location*>`) and don't forget to `delete` the allocated objects after use.

Comment: Are you sure you need dynamic allocation?

Comment: @JohnDibling OP is using a polymorphic Base class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ `new` dynamically allocates, the type of the expression will be a pointer.  In Java this is what (nearly) all object allocation is under the hood, you just don't see it.  "names" in Java are references to objects allocated through the JVM (the process is very interesting, I recommend reading about it).  However, Java copied C++'s syntax and made it do some very different things, so it's confusing to switch from Java to C++.

Since you are using polymorphism, you'll need a `std::vector` of pointers

```
std::vector<Location*> locations;
locations.push_back(new City{"New York", 9000, 1, 2});
```

When you are done with this vector you will need to `delete` everything you have allocated with new:

```
for (auto p : locations) {
    delete p;
}
```

Though all of this is best wrapped in another class that has the deletes handled in its *destructor*.

If you have no other pointers to these objects you can leverage [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as well, in which case you don't have to manually `delete`

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Location>> locations;
locations.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Location>{new City{"New York", 9000, 1, 2}});
```

with a type alias:

```
using LocPtr = std::unique_ptr<Location>;
std::vector<LocPtr> locations;
locations.push_back(LocPtr{new City("New York", 9000, 1, 2)});
```

Depending on your compiler's level of C++1y support you could also do

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Location>> locations;
locations.push_back(std::make_unique<City>("New York", 9000, 1, 2));
```

---

Another difference to be aware of: since you are using a pointer, you will have to use the `->` operator instead of the `.`

```
locations.at(0)->name(); // assuming class Location{} has a name member function
```

`p->attr` is equivalent to `(*p).attr`

**To make your class polymorphic** it will need to have at least one virtual function.  if nothing else, you should at least have `virtual ~Location(){}`.  Note that any function not marked `virtual` won't have run time look up done on it.

Comment: `locations.push_back(make_unique<City>("New York, 9000, 1, 2));` seems simplest.

Comment: True, I'll add it though its only in C++14

Comment: It's easily emulated in C++11 until then.  `template<class T,class...U> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(U...v){return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<U>(v)...));}` (nobody cares about the array version, but that's also easily done)